# ExtJS 4 code assist

Tags: eclipse, extjs, extjs4, code-assist

how can I write ExtJS code in Eclipse with autocompletion and other features?
I tried with SpketIDE, but there isn't a ext.jsb2 file in the ExtJS 4 package.

Has anyone done this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Refer to [this](http://forums.spket.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=1866&start=15) Spket forum post.

The Latest skpet jar is: http://www.agpad.com/downloads/com.spket.js_1.6.18.jar

JSB2 file for 4.0.0 is http://www.agpad.com/downloads/ext-4.0.0.jsb2

Comment: Another problem: it doesn't work for me, and neither for ExtJS 3.2.0. I followed this tutorial, http://bit.ly/aUF9WW, but I don't get code completion.

Comment: I don't use these.. so, I cannot give my experience. The tutorial seems to be for ExtJS 3.2.1. The above files are for the new verions. May be you are having some conflict? try posting a question at http://forums.spket.com/. I feel its some config issue that you are having

Comment: I'm currently developing ExtJS integration with JSDT: http://zulus.github.com/extjs-eclipse/

Comment: also when you define your classes, i found that if you pass the config as a json object it will not pick up on your methods. If you pass the config as a closure with private functions it picks up on these.

Answer (score 2):

Now, there is an eclipse plugin for ExtJs developed by Sencha Team.

http://www.sencha.com/products/complete-team

here is a video about it:
http://vimeo.com/49176749

I didn't use but it looks fine...

Comment: Great if you want to cough up $1000 for code completion...WTH?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the docs on the Spke docs: http://www.spket.com/extjs.html

"Click the Add File button, choose **sdk.jsb3** which can be found in build folder."